# How do I deal with transfer-Encoding chunked json using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, restful-url

I posted this the error below a few days ago and there were several responses. One suggested that the error comes up when the response is transfer-Encoding type chunked. What do I do to either tell the server not to chunk or fix my end so that ReadTemplate will work properly. And, BTW, I reading from WeatherUndergound's the REST service, if that's useful to know.

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for
response type [net.cheshiresgrin.currentConditions.Display] and
content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

and add the maven dependencies in your pom file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```